# Construct a convergence graph for operators and functionals (what follows from what)

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

To begin with we know about 3 convergences Normal (U), Strong (S), Weak (W), there are operators (A) and functionals (f). $U \rightarrow SA \rightarrow WA$ and $Sf \rightarrow Wf$, is something that I know for sure.

$U:$
$$A_m \rightarrow A \Leftrightarrow ||A_m-A||\rightarrow 0$$

$SA:$
$$A_m \underset{m \rightarrow \infty}{\stackrel s \longrightarrow} A \Leftrightarrow \forall x \in X: A_m x \underset{m \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} Ax$$

$WA:$
$$A_m \underset{m \rightarrow \infty}{\stackrel w \longrightarrow} A \Leftrightarrow \forall x \in X \; \forall f \in Y^*: f(A_m x) \underset{m \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} f(Ax)$$

$Sf:$
$$f_n \stackrel S \rightarrow f \Leftrightarrow ||f_n-f|| \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$

$Wf:$
$$f_n \stackrel w \longrightarrow f \Leftrightarrow \forall x \in X: f_n(x) \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} f(x)$$

---

Then as far as I understand, the functional is a specific type of operator that translates vector to scalar.

$X, Y$ - some vector, $x$ - some scalar

$$AX = Y$$

$$f(X) = x$$

---

So from all this I made an assumption that

$$
\leftrightarrow Sf \rightarrow Wf \\
U\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\downarrow\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\\
\rightarrow SA \rightarrow WA
$$

Sf is basically the same as U
Is this right? or are there any other connections that must be in that graph, also more mathematical explanation of what is going on here is appreciated.

---

UPD: After a talk with my teacher he corrected me in a few places, we assume that $A:X \rightarrow Y, Y=\mathbb{R}$($\mathbb{R}$ = Real numbers) In that case $U$ and $Sf$ is basically the same because $\underset{||x|| \leq 1}{sup}|f(x)|$ and $\underset{||x|| \leq 1}{sup}||Ax||$, if $Ax \in \mathbb{R}$ then $||Ax|| = |Ax|$

So
$$
 \rightarrow Wf \\
(U, Sf)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\updownarrow\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\\
\rightarrow SA \rightarrow WA
$$
I still dont understand why is there a full link between $Wf$ and $WA$ and as @s.harp said why is $Wf$ and $SA$ the same.

Comment: The names you use are somewhat nonstandard and the notation is actually painful to read, lol. That said, what you call Wf is the same as SA if the space of operators is from the vector space to the field. Since the field admits basically only one linear functional, WA is also the same as Wf. The other implications and equivalences you indicate are correct.

Comment: @s.harp Yeah, sorry its a little bit of language barrier. Is U and SA the same in R (real numbers), when operator translates vector to a number its the same as functional.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out thanks to @s.harp and my teacher, so. The answer depends on what operator we talk about, in case of $A: X \rightarrow Y, Y = \mathbb{R}$ the operator is basically the same as functional. (The functional is a special case of operator)

So right graph will look like
$$(U, Sf) \rightarrow (SA, Wf, WA)$$

---

**Why is that?**

$U=Sf$:

It's actually an axiom in my book but, as I mentioned in a question norm of functional is $\underset{||x|| \leq 1}{sup}|f(x)|$, norm of operator is $\underset{||x|| \leq 1}{sup}||Ax||$.

So if $Ax = \mathbb{R}$ then $||Ax|| = |Ax|$ And as I already mention $Ax$ is a functional in case of $Y = \mathbb{R}$
So
$$A_m \rightarrow A \Leftrightarrow ||A_m-A||\rightarrow 0$$
is the same as
$$f_n \stackrel S \rightarrow f \Leftrightarrow ||f_n-f|| \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$

---

$Wf=SA$:

It's the same as with $U=Sf$. $A_n x$, $Ax$ is the same as $f_n (x)$ and $f(x)$ for $A:X \rightarrow Y, Y = \mathbb{R}$

---

$WA=Wf$:

Let's take a look at the definition of $WA$:
$$A_m \underset{m \rightarrow \infty}{\stackrel w \longrightarrow} A \Leftrightarrow \forall x \in X \; \forall f \in Y^*: f(A_m x) \underset{m \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} f(Ax)$$

$Y^*$ for $Y = \mathbb{R}$ is still $\mathbb{R}$.

Now for this part, $f(A_m x) \underset{m \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} f(Ax)$

The most basic functional in $\mathbb{R}$ is $f(x)=kx$, if we take $k=1$ then we keep the functional the same, so $f(A_n x)=f(f_n(x))=f_n(x)$ and $f(Ax)=f(f(x))=f(x)$.

So that is the same as definition of Wf.

---

If I manage to find this graph for $A: X \rightarrow Y, Y \neq \mathbb{R}$. I'll update this.

Comment: Please do correct me if I'm wrong or just didn't tell any crucial part of proof. Or provide a helping hand with $Y \notin \Re$ I really don't want to leave it hanging but don't have a lot of time now.

Comment: Please use $\mathbb{R}$ to denote the real numbers, $\Re$ is usually used to denote the real part of a complex number. Further, I'm sure you meant to write $Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $Y\neq \mathbb{R}$ instead of $Y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $Y\notin\mathbb{R}$, respectively.